# How to unit test method returning Java string?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have plenty of methods which returns string which I need to unit test. Now challenge for me is is how do I do code coverage? For example, my method looks like the following:

```
Public String getSqlToDoXYZ(Myconfig config) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
sb.append(  "SELECT BLAH BLAH");
sb.append("WHERE ABC="+config.getABC());
return sb.toString() ;
}
```

How can I unit test such scenario? I am using Mockito to do unit testing. I am new to both Mockito and unit testing.

Comment: As a side note, you should really use prepared statements instead of concatenating parameters into your SQL.

Comment: [Link to documentation for JDBC Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for input. I cant user prepared statements as all of these are fixed queries and change at run time and above all they are normal sql not meant to be executed as prepared statements.

Comment: You can of change statements at runtime (see the section "Supplying Values for PreparedStatement Parameters"), and it will help you avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed elsewhere, using Strings for SQL statements is dangerous, regarding SQL injections. 
That being said, you simply have to call the method, and compare the result to a String you build "by hand" :

```
public void testBuildSqlToDoXYZ() throws Exception {

   WhateverYourObjectIs yourObject = new WhateverYourObjectIs();
   MyConfig myConfig = new MyConfig();
   myConfig.setABC("foo");

   String sql = yourObject.getSqlToDoXYZ(myConfig);
   assertEquals("SELECT BLAH BLAH WHERE ABC='foo'", sql);

}
```

Mockito would only be helpfull in this case if is impossible for you to create a "MyConfig" object by hand.

There might be something else in your code that makes that difficult, but you haven't really provided us enough info.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Sql are more tricky and long I just gave simple example it involves lot of complex joins etc. I dont think risk of SQL injection as my is desktop app will be running under secure firewall. So you are saying whatever my sql is I should know in advance and just validate in assert it.

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea of unit testing : you get a unit of code to execute with known inputs, and you compare the "actual" result (what your code under test returns) to the "expected" result (the one you know.) In case of Strings, it is actually pretty easy, since Java has comparison built-in. Mocks are helpfull when it's difficult to build the inputs, or when you need to test code that has side-effects that can not be simulated. When you're a bit more confortable with unit tests, see http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html for *much* more details.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any difficulties to test a method that returns a string.

```
public void testSqlToDoXYZ()
{
 MyObj testTarget = new MyObj(/*Parameters if needed*/);
 Config config = new Config();
 /*Config config = new ConfigMock();*/
 String expectedResult = "SELECT BLAH BLACH WHERE ABC=123;";
 assertEquals(epxectedResult, testTarget.getSqlToDoXYZ(config));
}
```

The key is, that you have to know your result. If the `config.getABC()` call could return different values, you have to make sure it always provides the same values for your test. So you might have to mock your `config` object or put fake data into your config provider.